# How do you execute a method and view the return value in the XCode debugger?

Tags: xcode, debugging

How do you execute methods in your program and display the return value. For example, how do I execute the following method

```
[self.view.subviews count]
```

when the program is stopped at a breakpoint?

Also, how do you view the value of a property w/o hovering over it w/ the cursor?

This is an example of a method call so just view it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "print object" or "print" statements in gdb. Let's say you have an array with `@"one"` and `@"two"` as its contents. To print the array do this

```
gdb> po myArray
```

To print only the last array object:

```
gdb> po [myArray lastObject]
```

To print a simple scalar value use "print" with type information parameter like this:

```
gdb> p (int)[myArray count]
```

Comment: When I tried this 

p (int) self.currentIndex

or

p (int) [self currentIndex]

where currentIndex is an int property of the class where the breakpoint is located, nothing is displayed (gdb) on the next line? I can see the value is 1 in the Local window.

Comment: I see know the window has several views one of which is Debugger Output which displays some values. However p (int) [self.view.subviews count] displays "There is no member names view" when it is a property of self?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are in the right stack frame? Try typing `gdb> l` to see the code around your current breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

GDB doesn't know what return type to expect from a method, so you have to tell it by casting the result:

```
(gdb) print (int)[myArray count]
```